# Zend Framework: Setting routes from an .INI file

Tags: php, zend-framework

So I'm setting my routes like this:

```
;Custom routes
routes.index.route = "/index/page/:year"
routes.index.defaults.controller = index
routes.index.defaults.action = index
routes.index.defaults.module = default
```

In my Bootstrap file

```
$router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
$router->addConfig($config, 'routes');
```

And when I go to `url/index/page/FOO`I get an error that the action page doesn't exists!

What I'm doing wrong?

Error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Action_Exception' with message 'Action "foo" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()'`

Comment: Do you have pageAction inside your index controller?

Comment: No I don't, I just want to set a custom route

Comment: Yep, but your custom route are correctly configured, I think.

Comment: `routes.index.route = "/index/page/:year"` are your custom route. The `index` is you `controller`, the `page` is your `action` and the `:year` is your `param`. When you access the url, the controller with the action page will be called, so, you need to have this action inside your controller otherwise Zend say you have not the "page" action..

Comment: I think so, but then way I'm getting this: Post Updated.

Comment: You need to put this in your question because I'm not a clairvoyant. Wait a second, I go investigate.

Comment: I've modifided to `routes.index.route = "/index/:year"` and still doesn't work, I'm getting the same error when I access `url.com/index/foo`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6528/discussion-between-gabriel-santos-and-uffo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you need to have the action inside your controller.

If access index/foo/year, you need to have the fooAction to work. if have index/bar/year, need the barAction to Zend call, and so on.